# How many stored procedures I can create in a single database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to find out the maximum number of stored procedures we can create in a single database.

Answer (score 9):

[Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) says:

> Database objects include objects such as tables, views, stored
>   procedures, user-defined functions, triggers, rules, defaults, and
>   constraints. The sum of the number of all objects in a database cannot
>   exceed 2,147,483,647.

In other words, there are no hard upper limit specifically for stored procedures, but the total number of objects must be no more than 2,147,483,647. And I would say, if this limit is of any concern to you, you need to re-evaluate your database design.

Comment: Also valid for instances of Microsoft SQL Server 2012, 2014, 2016, and 2017.