# Maximum count of stored procedure in SQL

Tags: sql-server

How many stored procedures at maximum I can have in a SQL Server database? Any limitations?

As of now I have 422 stored procedures in my database.

I am worrying to add more in the future. Please suggest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many stored procedures I can create in a single database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321199/how-many-stored-procedures-i-can-create-in-a-single-database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per [This Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server)

> Database objects include objects such as tables, views, stored
>   procedures, user-defined functions, triggers, rules, defaults, and
>   constraints. The sum of the number of all objects in a database cannot
>   exceed 2,147,483,647.